# Disable sameSite cookie policy in Firefox (developer edition)

Tags: firefox, cookies, mozilla, same-origin-policy, samesite

There's cases I when I want to run my front end as localhost and have it connect to a remote server for API requests. However, when trying to set cookies, Firefox won't allow it in cases where sameSite="Lax". It shows:

"Some cookies are misusing the “SameSite“ attribute, so it won’t work as expected "
and
"Cookie “connect.sid” has “SameSite” policy set to “Lax” because it is missing a “SameSite” attribute, and “SameSite=Lax” is the default value for this attribute."

In Google Chrome, simply allowing these sameSite="Lax" cookies is done by [disabling these policies in the settings](https://support.siteimprove.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360007364778-Turning-off-Google-Chrome-SameSite-Cookie-Enforcement).

However, for the developer edition of Firefox, I wasn't able to find such option.
How do I disable this for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 20):

Go to `about:config` in Firefox and make sure you have the following settings:

```
network.cookie.sameSite.laxByDefault: false
network.cookie.sameSite.noneRequiresSecure: false
```